# R: Plotting Results of Multiple Simulations

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following function which simulates random numbers, takes the cumulative sum of all numbers generated - until the sum exceeds 10 for the first time:

```
simulate_until_boundary <- function() {
# starting value
    sum <- 5
    count <- 1
    numbers <- c(sum)
    
    while ( sum <= 10) {
        num <- rnorm(1,0,1)
        sum <- sum + num
        count <- count + 1
        numbers <- c(numbers, sum)
    }
    
    list("final_sum" = sum, "iterations" = count, "cumulative_sums" = numbers)
}
```

I then repeated this function 100 times and plotted the results:

```
# Repeat simulation 100 times
sims <- replicate(100, simulate_until_boundary(), simplify = FALSE)

max_len <- max(sapply(sims, length))

# Pad results
sims <- lapply(sims, function(x) {c(x, rep(NA, max_len - length(x)))})

sims <- do.call(rbind, sims)

#colors
colors <- rep(c("blue", "green", "red", "purple", "black"), each = 20)

matplot(1:max_len, t(sims), type = "l", xlab = "Count", ylab = "Cumulative Sum", col = colors)
```

[image]

**My Question:** I want to modify this code so that the first time the sum goes below 0, it simply stays at 0 until the sum starts to go back up.

For example:

- Suppose the current sum = 0.3
- The next number generated is -4 : the current sum becomes 0
- The next number generated is -2: the current sum still stays at 0
- The next number generated is 3: the current sum now becomes 3

Here is my attempt at this:

```
simulate_until_boundary <- function() {
    # starting value
    sum <- 5
    count <- 1
    numbers <- c(sum)
    
    while ( sum <= 10) {
        num <- rnorm(1,0,1)
        sum <- sum + num
        # if sum goes below 0, reset it to 0
        if (sum < 0) {
            sum <- 0
        }
        count <- count + 1
        numbers <- c(numbers, sum)
    }
    
    list("final_sum" = sum, "iterations" = count, "cumulative_sums" = numbers)
}
```

But I can't plot the results now :

```
# Repeat simulation 100 times
sims <- replicate(100, simulate_until_boundary(), simplify = FALSE)

max_len <- max(sapply(sims, length))

# Pad results
sims <- lapply(sims, function(x) {c(x, rep(NA, max_len - length(x)))})

sims <- do.call(rbind, sims)

#colors
colors <- rep(c("blue", "green", "red", "purple", "black"), each = 20)

matplot(1:max_len, t(sims), type = "l", xlab = "Count", ylab = "Cumulative Sum", col = colors)
```

I get the following error:

```
Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log = log, recycle = TRUE) : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

**Can someone please show me what I am doing wrong and what can I do to fix this?**

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OP here: I think I was able to find a solution :

```
simulate_until_boundary <- function() {
    # starting value
    sum <- 5
    count <- 1
    numbers <- c(sum)
    
    while ( sum <= 10) {
        num <- rnorm(1,0,1)
        sum <- sum + num
        # if sum goes below 0, reset it to 0
        if (sum < 0) {
            sum <- 0
        }
        count <- count + 1
        numbers <- c(numbers, sum)
    }
    
    list("final_sum" = sum, "iterations" = count, "cumulative_sums" = numbers)
}

# Repeat simulation 100 times
sims <- replicate(100, simulate_until_boundary(), simplify = FALSE)

# Extract cumulative_sums from each list
sims <- lapply(sims, function(x) x$cumulative_sums)

max_len <- max(sapply(sims, length))

# Pad results
sims <- lapply(sims, function(x) {c(x, rep(NA, max_len - length(x)))})

sims <- do.call(rbind, sims)

#colors
colors <- rep(c("blue", "green", "red", "purple", "black"), each = 20)

matplot(1:max_len, t(sims), type = "l", xlab = "Count", ylab = "Cumulative Sum", col = colors)
```

[image]

Comment: Please explain what was the solution.